# overwrite extend jqGrid Navgrid method

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to extend the jqGrid "navgrid" method to add custom functionality (i.e adding a "navButtonAdd" or "filterToolbar") for ALL my table grids. I have about 100 pages, all working good with jqGrid v4.6.0, all with the same structure and already using "navGrid" method, and don't want to write "navButtonAdd" or "filterToolbar" in each page.
So (according to Oleg's example in other answer), I first tried this:

```
/* this is my global.js file, which is included for every page, of course AFTER jquery.jqGrid.src.js */
var oldNavGrid = $.fn.jqGrid.navGrid;

$.jgrid.extend({
    navGrid: function() {   
        var ret = oldNavGrid.call(arguments);
        //... do something else, such navButtonAdd or filterToolbar...
        return ret;
    }
});

//...

/* this is the structure of every page */

var $myGrid = $("#$myGrid");
$myGrid.jqGrid({
    //grid options...
})

$myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#myPager", 
{edit:false, add:true, del:true, search:true, refresh:true}, {}, {}, {}, {})
```

but when I call "navGrid" I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", pointing to jquery.jqGrid.src.js:8911

Then I tried different ways of overwriting, such

```
var oldNavGrid = $.fn.jqGrid.navGrid;

$.fn.jqGrid.navGrid = function() {  
    var ret = oldNavGrid.call(arguments);
    //... do something else...
    return ret;
};
```

always getting similar errors.
Can someone tell me a solution for what I want to do?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `oldNavGrid.apply(this, arguments)` instead of `oldNavGrid.call(arguments)` which don't forwards `this` and uses `arguments` as *the first* (and the only) parameter of `navGrid` instead of forward all options. Alternatively you can use `oldNavGrid.call(this, ...)`, but you need includes *all parameters* of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) explicitly instead of usage array-like object `arguments`.

Comment: Thanks!! oldNavGrid.apply(this, arguments) works fine! 
Do you consider this solution as the best way to apply additional default functionality to all grids?